# Google Cloud SDK is trying to upload itself to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have been working on a website and I decieded to use google app engine to host it. I have been able use the config file to try and deploy with no errors in the config. I am using the google cloud SDK to upload and deploy my files. Whenever I try to deploy the SDK says it is uploading 30,000 files. I only have 11 files I need to upload. I think the SDK is trying to upload itself to cloud storage. My website files are in a www subfolder under my public directory where the SDK is installed. On my old computer I was able to move all the SDK files to my home directory and use my public folder as the sourse. When I try to do that now it says gcloud is not found. I am using gcloud app deploy and running windows 11. My old computer was running windows 10. I am not sure if that matters. I am also not sure if I need to specify anything in my app.yaml file. If anyone could help that would be great.
This is my app.yaml file:

```
 runtime: php74

handlers:
- url: /www/index.html
 static_files: /www/index.html
 upload: /www/index.html, /www/campsite-form-results.php, /www/contact_us.php
```

This is the command line screenshot: [image: SDK screenshot.]
Plese let me know if there is any other information need to add.

Comment: Don't post links to images, always include the images in the question

Comment: Ok, I would of but I am new to stack overflow and I do not have enough reputation to put images directly in the question.

Comment: Ok, no worries c:

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected since `gcloud` will upload everything that is in the path where is the `app.yaml` file.

I suspect that `C:/Users/evanh/public` contains a lot of things (even hidden folders) and not only your files for the app.

Create a new folder and put there your code, then try to deploy the app from that new folder.

---

EDIT

Since this was the accepted answer I'm editing this to include John's suggestion using his answer:

---

As a good practice, create a **.gcloudignore** file and specify what you do not want uploaded. You can see more info here:

[gcloud topic gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)

[Ignoring files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#ignoring_files)

Comment: Although your answer might solve this question, your answer is not a good solution. Most real-world projects will have numerous files that should not be uploaded. Items like .git repo information, credentials, secrets, etc. The best practice is to specify what should not be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **.gcloudignore** file and specify what you do not want uploaded otherwise everything is uploaded.

[gcloud topic gcloudignore](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)

[Ignoring files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#ignoring_files)